Iptables rule with per-connection and per-packet conditions
For example, I have 2 conditions for passing in iptables (input chain): destination tcp port - condition 1, source mac address - condition 2
Is it possible to create the rule or some rules, that will check condition 1 per-connection (only first packet to establish connection or not), and condition 2 per-packet (first packet to establish the same connection or not + every packet of this established connection to pass packet or not)?
And if so, how to do it?
